# Metallic material in internal

Tags: materials, game-engine

I have a racing game.I want it to be advanced racing game (in materials,model,logic bricks,AI).So, the question is,How to make a metallic material like this[image: metallic material]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fake reflections (quite the same as a Matcap), here is a tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1t7fMKVuQs